# ListPlot with 3

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to have 3 x axes labels like in the image below? I would like to have letters exactly under corresponding ticks. I am considering overlaying three plots with separate x axis together with `Show` but this does not seem like a clean solution.

[image]

Comment: show us your problem and code please

Comment: You can use `Ticks` or `FrameTicks` (please look up `Ticks` in the docs), and use a `Column` expression for each tick label.  You should be able to handle it from here—let us know if there's anything that's unclear.

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Transpose[{RandomSample[Range[50], 20], RandomInteger[100, 20]}];

labels = Column[#, Spacings -> .5, Alignment -> Center] & /@ 
  Join[List /@ data[[All, 1]], RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], {20, 3}], 2];

epilog = MapThread[Inset[#2, {#[[1]], 0}, {0, 1.2}] &, {data, labels}];

legend = labels /. {(Spacings -> _) -> Spacer[1], Column->Row};

ListPlot[List /@ data, 
 Epilog -> epilog,
 PlotLegends -> legend,
 PlotRange -> {0, 100}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Scaled[.2], Automatic}},
 Ticks -> {data[[All, 1]], Automatic},
 TicksStyle -> {FontOpacity -> 0, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can place a newline ("\n") to create rows in a text string such as "1\nA\n-".  To automate this a bit to mimic your graph:

```
row1 = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
row2 = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
row3 = {"-", "-", "H", "H", "H", "H", "-", "-", "-", "-"};
ticks = Table[Style[tick1[[i]] <> "\n" <> tick2[[i]] <> "\n" <> tick3[[i]], Bold, 18], {i, 10}];
ticks = Transpose[{Range[10], ticks}];

data = Range[10];
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {ticks, None}},
 PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {1, 0.5}}]
```

[image: 3 rows of tick labels]

The `PlotRangePadding` option is needed to provide the extra space for the 3 rows of tick labels.